# Create Stored Procedure for VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure for the view as shown below, but it's throwing an error

> Incorrect syntax near  'N'

If I removed the quote, then it works. Please suggest me how to put value N in quotes.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_VIEW] 
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE('
        CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SP_VIEW]
        AS
            SELECT * 
            FROM [dbo].[ACTIVITY] 
            WHERE IND = 'N'')
END
```

Comment: You need to double the single quotes, because they are inside a string.  I consider misuse of quotes to be a typo and vote to close such questions.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not supports here-string so you have to double every `'`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[SP_VIEW] 
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE('
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SP_VIEW]
AS
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ACTIVITY] 
where IND=''N''
');
END
```

Azure Feedback: [Add support for here-strings i T-SQL](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34385422-add-support-for-here-strings-i-t-sql)